# guilliani framework do drag function

Tags: c++, user-interface, fpga, nios

i'm working on altera board DE2-115 cyclone 4 and im using a framework called "Guilliani" dedicated for NIOS, the problem is i can't find any documentation no videos no forums nothing at all even google coudn't help me, hopefully some of you have heard of it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no documentation simply use something else. Its obviously a framework with no future in this case . I never heared of it either. What do you need it for? Maybe i can suggest you a alternative.  Edit: http://guiliani.de/images/TES-Media/Guiliani_doc_1.5/index.html

Comment: believe me it's not my choice to use such unknown framework, the wiered thing is there's nothing about it not even in the official web site http://guiliani.de/

Comment: As i said, then explain it to whoever wants you to work with it. There is no way of using a framework without docu. Maybe mail the author

Comment: i have already tried that, til now i have used the help link on the site as my only learning source, but it's not enough, well seems like i'm the only one on earth working on it -_- nevermind thank you Etixpp